# Export set of layers in Pixelmator

Tags: pixelmator

So I'm new to graphic design as a whole, but I've worked with layered PSD files before. I don't have Photoshop, but I do have a copy of Pixelmator. Clearly a cheaper alternative, but obviously not Photoshop.

So, I created a layered file in Pixelmator and now I want to implement it. Obviously there are situations where a couple layers together need to make a single image. How can I export those layers **without** copying the layers and making a new file just to export them?

Can't I export those layers from that master file?

Answer (score 11):

You can merge those layers (select layers in the Layers palette, Control-click and choose Merge Layers), and then drag the layer to Desktop from the Layers palette.

Once you exported those layers, undo the merge if you want to keep layers for later.

Comment: ♥ gotta love what makes (made) OSX such a good OS. Good ol' drag and drop of everything. Kudos to Pixelmator's developers for keeping it alive. Also: if you select multiple layers and drag them out, multiple PNGs will be saved.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can "Group" layers together instead of merging them and it works the same. With a group, you might not need to undo it.

Comment: I love you for this answer this have cost me 10s of hours  so far. Those days are over now.